# Rails + Docker: ffi gem update today broke deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler, ffi, gemfile

So i'm using docker to develop a rails app locally and today out of the blue (after rebuilding without cache) I started getting the following issue when running `docker-compose run` to start unicorn:

```
bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/usr/local/bundle/bin/unicorn)
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find ffi-1.9.10 in any of the sources
```

In fact, my sidekiq container was raising this as well. I realized ffi updated to 1.9.11 sometime recently, but shouldn't this dependency have been resolved within bundler?

Other info: Ruby 2.2.5 with the full 2.2.5 docker image. I do my bundling in my dockerfile to keep things cached between builds and i do not copy my Gemfile.lock into the docker image on building (following [this](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application) process). ffi-1.9.10 appears in my local non-docker gemfile.lock as a top-level dependency, but not in my Gemfile. I resolved this problem for now by explicitly requiring 1.9.10 in my Gemfile but i'm not really satisfied with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem, i made a lot of changes:

bundler pristine --all , bundle install , bundle update , the same with docker-compose run , put ffi on the Gemfile , delete the gemfile.lock , and try all again ...

looks like nothing works, them I do a "docker-compose up --build"

and all go ok

Im not sure what made it worK :S